# React Native, "setState() on unmounted component" warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a working piece of code that triggers warning (the code should login to the REST and turn off Activity Indicator). I don't understand how my component could be unmounted as I bind onLoginPressed on button tap, after all possible mounts should already be finished. Please help me to get rid of it and understand the cause of the warning...
UPD: Thanks to the comments I figured out that component is unmounted and componentWillUnmount is invoked... But I don't understand why and when it is happening...

> "Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined
>   component."

Here is my code, warning is triggered by second `setState`:

```js
onLoginPressed(){
    console.log('Attempted to login with: '+this.state.username);
    this.setState({showProgress: true});

    AuthService.login({
      login: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password
    }, (results)=> {
      this.setState(Object.assign({ // have to create a solid Object with all states to be changed at once
        showProgress: false // turning off ActivityIndicator
      }, results));

      if(results.success && this.props.onLogin){
        this.props.onLogin(); // Yey! We logged in! Let's move to the next View
      }
    });
  }
```

...
AuthService.js:

```js
login (creds, callback) {
    fetch(CFG.AUTH_URL)
      .then((response)=> {
        if((response.status >= 200) && (response.status < 300)){
          return response.json();
        }
        throw {
          serverError: (response.status == 500) || (response.status == 501),
          unknownError: (response.status != 500) || (response.status != 501)
        };
      })
      .then((result)=> {
          AsyncStorage.multiSet([ // Have to save login+password and session_hash for later use...
            [authKey, JSON.stringify(creds)],
            [sessionKey, result.data.session_hash]
          ], (err)=> {
            if (err) throw err;
          });
          return callback({success: true});
      }
      })
      .catch((err)=> {
        return callback(err);
      });
  }// end of login
```

Comment: Add `componentWillUnmount` and check if and why it actually unmounts.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't get the idea why it actually unmounts... Starring at the call stack dosen't help, because I just don't understand what is going on. The component updated and than, unmounted... Maybe there is a some kind of mixins or code samples to get more info on what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Федор Усаков, I ran into this problem as well. I found that the component was re-rendering due to setting the state in the callback function of `AuthService.login()`. The issue (in this situation) with `setState`:

> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState
>   and calls may be batched for performance gains.

*from React docs*

My guess is that the state is not being set immediately and then `this.props.onLogin()` is called. This unmmounts the component before the state could be set, and voila, **warning**.

To get mine to work I removed the conditional and the call to `onLogin()` and added a `shouldComponentUpdate()` method to the `Login` class. In the `shouldComponentUpdate()` I placed the removed conditional and call. Like so:

```
onLoginButtonPress() {
    // some code

    AuthService.login({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    }, (results) => {
        this.setState({
            ...results,
            showProgress: false
        });
    });
}

shouldComponentUpdate() {
    if (this.state.loginSuccess && this.props.onLogin) {
        this.props.onLogin();
    }
    return true;
}
```

This ensures the state has been set, the component then re-renders and because `this.state.loginSuccess` is now true, call `this.props.onLogin()` which causes `Login` to unmount.